# НАВРОДЕ ― значение и употребление слова

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, выбор-слов, значение-слов, части-речи

1. Слово часто встречается у В. Распутина ([Прощание с Матерой](https://books.google.ee/books?id=u4RUDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT46&lpg=PT46&dq=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5&source=bl&ots=cTUvrvmPZe&sig=O0twMnp6nq8l0Ywt44HlZ_kVnVo&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi5quu2hZveAhVCjCwKHT1vAWY4ChDoATAHegQIABAB#v=onepage&q=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5&f=false)):

> Закружили меня звездочки... **навроде** как обмерла, ниче не помню, кто я, где я, че было.
>
> Я ж тут была, на мне лежало доглядывать. И что водой зальет, **навроде** тоже как я виноватая.

2. Используется это слово и в современных переводах ([К. Тойбин. Бруклин](http://loveread.ec/read_book.php?id=67487&p=60); перевод с английского С. Ильина):

   > А вот мать Джорджа Шеридана выглядела **навроде** старой герцогини, у которой ничего, кроме большой шляпы, кое-каких древних драгоценностей и превеликого самоуважения, не осталось.

Хотелось бы понять, **почему** довольно редкое слово употреблено в переводном тексте (ведь есть же «вроде»). В чем особенность?
Какие, собственно, значения имеет слово **навроде** и к какой части речи относится?
Используете ли Вы в речи это словечко, в каком контексте?

Comment: Это уж на совести переводчика. Может, и в оригинале употреблено какое-то просторечие.

Comment: В оригинале всё складно: George Sheridan's mother, she saw, looked like an elderly duchess who had been left with nothing except a large hat...

Answer (score 2):

Словари говорят, что [НАВРОДЕ](http://%D0%9D%D0%90%D0%92%D0%A0%D0%9E%D0%94%D0%95) - просторечный вариант слова *ВРОДЕ*, а [ВРОДЕ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5) может быть предлогом или частицей. Я его (НАВРОДЕ) не использую и не знаком с теми, кто его употребляет, даже в шутку. Слишком уж сниженный стиль, на мой взгляд.

Answer (score 1):

Словарь синонимов (Тришин, 2013) приводит следующие значения:
*будто, вроде, кажется, как будто, наподобие*.

В вашем первом примере сочетание **навроде как** имеет значение **как будто**. Во всех случаях употребления слово является просторечным (словари так его и помечают).

Что касается перевода, употребление слова (вместо "вроде") едва ли в нём оправдано, поскольку (судя по нескольким страницам текста) это не речь персонажа, да и повествование ведётся не от первого лица.

Comment: Mать выглядела навроде (=наподобие?) старой герцогини? Или как старая герцогиня?

Comment: В этом примере "вроде". Я сейчас уточнил, к чему какой комментарий относится (не сразу заметил второй пример).

Comment: Я бы предложил "двухходовку", которая, на мой взгляд, должна работать всегда: (1) заменить "навроде" на "вроде"; (2) если предложение остается просторечивым, искать подходящий синoним для "вроде".